# react-query streaming ssr in Next.js 13

Tags: server-side-rendering, next.js13, react-query

I was trying to work with react-query using Next.js 13.

I used prefetchQuery+Hydrate referencing https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/ssr

It worked fine, but I found out that streaming using suspense does not work when working with react-query, and because of this, it took so long when switching pages. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The TanStack community came up with some workarounds to use react query with next13, which involve handling the hydration yourself or passing the initial data to a client component from a server component.
using this package will fix it

`@tanstack/react-query-next-experimental`

source:
https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/examples/react/nextjs-suspense-streaming